# Showing a markov chain is reversible

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

Can anyone help me figure out how to show that this markov chain process is reversible? $$ P =
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0.5 & 0.25 & 0.25 \\
        0.5 & 0 & 0.5 \\
        0.25 & 0.25 & 0.5 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
Does this mean $π_iP_{ij} = π_jP_{ji}$? If so, I am a little confused on how to start this. $π_0P_{01} = π_1P_{10}$ to begin?

Comment: Yes, it means the steady state satisfies $\pi_i P_{ij} = \pi_j P_{ji}$ for all $(i,j)$.  Can you compute the steady state and then verify?  Alternatively, write out the equations $\pi_i P_{ij} = \pi_j P_{ji}$ for all relevant $(i,j)$ and (with knowlege of teh $P_{ij}$) solve for the unknowns $\pi_i$ (or reach a contradiction)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an irreducible aperiodic Markov chain on a finite state space, so there exists a unique stationary distribution $\pi$ which satisfies $\pi P=\pi$ and $\sum_{i=0}^2\pi_i = 1$. This yields the system of equations
\begin{align}
-\frac12\pi_0 +\frac12\pi_1+\frac14\pi_2 &= 0\\
\frac14\pi_0 + -\pi_1+ \frac14\pi_2&= 0\\
\pi_0+\pi_1+\pi_2&=1,
\end{align}
with solution
$$
\pi = \left(\frac25,\frac15,\frac25\right).
$$
The time reversal of $P$ with respect to $\pi$ is given by
$$
P^\star_{ij} = \frac{\pi_j}{\pi_i}P_{ji}.
$$
Computing $P^\star$, we see that $P^\star=P$. It follows that $P$ is reversible.

Comment: Why is $π_0$ + $π_1$ + $π_2$ = 0, not 1 like usual?

Comment: And also, where did you get those 3 equations in general?

Comment: \begin{align}
\pi P &= \pi\\
\sum_i \pi_i &= 1
\end{align}

Comment: Perfect, and I got it to work with Gaussian elimination. Thank you!